# NullPointerException for a 2d Array

Tags: java, arrays, nullpointerexception, 2d

```
map = new BufferedImage[width][height];
  for(int i=0;i<height;i++){
      for(int j=0;j<width;j++){    
  if(charMap[j][i] == Mountains.indentifier) {      
    if ( j+1 < width && j-1 >= 0){
        if(charMap[j-1][i] != Mountains.indentifier && charMap[j+1][i] != Mountains.indentifier) {            
            map[j][i]= tileGrid[1][10];
         }
    }    
    else {
        map[j][i]= tileGrid[8][10];
    }
   }
}
```

this is the code I'm using to try to check the 2D array by checking each tile around the cell but I seem to be getting a nullpointerexception I'm wondering if anyone can help?

Comment: On which line do you get the exception?  What did you learn when you ran this in the debugger and inspected all the variable values when the exception was thrown?

Comment: Well the nullpointerexception is from if ( j+1 < width && j-1 >= 0) code because without that code I get a ArrayIndexOutofBoundsException and II understand why that happens

Comment: That line cannot throw a NullPointerException.

Comment: The StackTrace from the NullPointerException should tell you the exact line where the Exception was thrown.  You'd be better served to learn how to debug a little than to have someone on this site tell you what's wrong.

Comment: yea I figured it out it was because I didn't place values into the rest of the array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am suspecting that you are getting the NullPointerException from `charMap[j][i] == Mountains.indentifier` line.

Make sure that you initialize inner arrays for both charMap and map as suggested by Geoff.

Answer (score 0):

You've only allocated the outer array.

You need to allocate each of the inner arrays.

So:

```
map = new BufferedImage[width][height];
for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
{
    map[i] = new BufferedImage[height];
}
```

Comment: i edited it and I get the nullpointerexception from this code "if ( j+1 < width && j-1 >= 0)" without that code the array has a possibility of going outside the array but I don't understand why I'm getting a nullpointerexception

Comment: You can't get a NullPointerException from that line. They're all primitive types. 
I'd try debugging again and finding out what line you actually got it on.

Comment: I figured it out it turns out I wasn't placing values in the rest of the array when I initialize the array

Comment: Good to hear! I would suggest learning how to use Eclipse and the debugger that is included. That will help you a lot. :)